# HttpSendRequest 12005 error

Tags: php, c++, upload

i have a tiny program that will upload a file onto a server. for testing purpose i used my own local server which i created by WebAmp software. my program will upload files by using  a PHP script that will accept the files from program and stores them on to the server at the specified place. now i am confused on this, that where i have to place this PHP file in my system so that my program will interact with this script and send the file successfully. here is my code

```
int main()
{

    static TCHAR frmdata[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"D:\\er.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfile contents  here\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n";
    static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858"; 

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("MyBrowser",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
     if(!hSession)
    {
     cout<<"Error: InternetOpen";  
    }


    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("http://localhost"),INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
     if(!hConnect)
    {
     cout<<"Error: InternetConnect";  
    }

    //HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",_T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
    LPCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("*/*"), NULL};
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",
                                     _T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL,
                                     rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 1);
    if(hRequest==NULL)
    {
     cout<<"Error: HttpOpenRequest";  
    }

    BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
    if(!sent)
    {
     cout<<"Error: HttpSendRequest "<<GetLastError();
     }


    //close any valid internet-handles
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

PHP script

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './'; // Relative Upload Location of data file

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) {
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
echo "File ". $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully. ";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully moved. ";
}

else
print_r($_FILES);
}

else {
echo "Upload Failed!!!";
print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The lpszServerName parameter should be a hostname, not a URL.

Change `http://localhost` to just `localhost`.

Put this code below `HTTPSendRequest` to print the response headers and content

```
//Print the first 2k of the response headers and content
char buffer[2048] = {};
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
BOOL success = HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, buffer, &bufferSize, NULL);
if(!success)
{
    std::cout<<"Error: HttpQueryInfo "<< GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
success = InternetReadFile(hRequest, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bufferSize); 
if(!success)
{
    std::cout << "Error: InternetReadFile " << GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

Comment: when i did this, no output is shown.. and when i press enter button, the console window disappears

Comment: What output would you expect?  You have none unless there's an error.  If you want to retrieve any data you would probably want to use `InternetReadFile` to do so, or `HttpQueryInfo` to get the status code or response headers.

Comment: to be a correct program, or when it works fine without any error,  it has to save that file in some location in my PC. but when i search for this file, it only shows the original file not the uploaded file... which means that my program still have some error

Comment: The change I suggested was to fix your 12005 error.  If you add the code I just added to the answer it may help you debug why the correct data is not being uploaded.